# Will these observations be of any help in calculating $n!$ faster?

Tags: factorial

Well, hello.

There's a recent observation I had when trying to figure out an easy and time-saving way to calculate $n !$:

---

If $f(x) = 4x^2 + 2x $,
$$ f(1)\cdot  f(2)\cdot f(3)\cdot  \dots \cdot f(n) = (2n + 1)!,$$ and
$$ f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdot f\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\cdot f\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)\cdot  \dots \cdot f\left(\frac{2n+1}{2}\right) = (2n)!.$$

Will these observations be of any help in calculating $n!$ faster ?

Comment: Faster than what?

Comment: I suppose you think you are only mutliplying half as many times. But to compute $f(x)$, you must perform 4 multiplications and one addition. So this doesn't appear to save time -- and in fact is more costly than just doing the original multiplications, right?

Comment: Well, faster than nothing but direct multiplication from $1$ to $n$ ?

Comment: I intend to make it faster for people who don't want approximations - those who want exact answers.

Comment: I am looking forward to make the calculation of factorials by hand as simple as possible.

Comment: Those people who find it difficult to make use of Stirling's approximation (because of the fractional exponents involved) may look forward to doing the calculation in some other way. My intention is to help them.

Comment: A bit of Vedic Maths wil do the trick in making this calculation faster.

Comment: Excuse me, did anyone downvote this question now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a trivial rewrite of the factorial's definition.
$$n!=\prod_{i=1}^n i \implies (2n+1)!=\prod_{i=1}^{2n+1} i = \prod_{i=1}^{n} (2i)(2i+1) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} f(i)$$
The same goes for the even factorials, I'll leave it to you to show that one. So, no, it will not be faster. You will have $n$ products for $(2n+1)!$, but you will also have to calculate $f(i)$ $n$ times. So you will have to calculate a sum and $3$ products at each step i.e. $f(i)=4\cdot i\cdot i + 2\cdot i$. So overall you have $3n$ products and $n$ sums which is definitely slower than $2n+1$ products.

Comment: What about that calculation ? Will it make things easier (if not faster) ?

Comment: @Spectre this isn't a chat forum, but I am good. I ran some benchmark tests and your method was about 30 per cent slower. As for 'easier', well that is a matter of perspective. Personally I definitely think your method is more complicated. But up to you, pick an $n$ (like around 10) and calculate $n!$ on paper using both methods. Which was easier?

Comment: I used a bit of Vedic maths too and it was sufficiently fast. I tried to calculate $10!$ and it was simple.

Comment: I dunno what it will be like for bigger numbers.

Comment: Like, it is $30$% slower than direct multiplication ?

Comment: I think this method will be useful enough so as to write $n!$ using its factors.

Comment: Okay try $n=20$. And do both methods from scratch. As in don't store any previous knowledge, i.e. the values of $f(i)$ or calculating $20!$ by starting from $10!$. I think if you do both methods purely from scratch, you will find that your method is slower and more complicated. Perhaps just write out both for a smaller $n$ and then observe how many steps you took.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111945/discussion-between-spectre-and-tomasliam).

Comment: 30 per cent as in if the usual method took 10 seconds, yours took 13 seconds.

Comment: Oh... ok ........

Comment: I did the calculation on paper for (10!) and I did it in less than 1.5 minutes (I think so, but definitely I exceeded a minute when doing the calculation).

Comment: Did you do it on paper ?

Comment: I didn't go for the programmatic approach (or computer based tests)